# Netstat doesn't show URLs while streaming from Youtube

Tags: networking, netstat

Learning about networks and trying to make sense of `netstat` output. This is the main confusion:

When I run the command, there are no known URLs. For example, I'm listening a Youtube streaming and was expecting to see UDP for the streaming. Am I expecting something that is not? Any help?

Slice of the output:

```
tcp        0      0 arco:43424              lhr25s15-in-f1.1e:https ESTABLISHED
udp        0      0 arco:bootpc             ttrouter.lan:bootps     ESTABLISHED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much anything running in a web browser, like youtube, will use only HTTP and HTTP-based protocols like WebSockets. Web browsers forbid non-HTTP connections by websites for security reasons. So you're not usually going to see UDP, except possibly for HTTP-over-QUIC and HTTP 3.

Looking into the network monitor in firefox while while watching a Video on Youtube, I can see a few requests to URLs like https://r4---sn-4g5e6nzz.googlevideo.com/videoplayback, returning webp (video) content.
Also in the firefox network monitor, the remote address is displayed as [2a00:1450:4001:1::9]:443 (IPv6).

Using `netstat -tpen` I can see a matching connection:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
[...]
tcp6       0      0 (censored)              2a00:1450:4001:1::9:443 ESTABLISHED 1000       8120905    8478/firefox
```

Comment: very clever. thanks!